# Как настроить таблицы Word

Tags: ms-word

есть таблица. При размещении данных программно в документ Word возникает сложная ситуация. нужно перенос сделать только для длинного текста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/yvX37OAK-Sh4IA  - это файл

а вот сам файл, всю голову сломал.

Comment: Сделайте стиль и только ему разрешите переносы

Comment: а как я заранее программно узнаю, влезает ли текст или не влезает в страницу?

Comment: Тогда разрешите всем - кто влезет, не будет переноситься. В чем проблема?

Comment: Виноват, не досмотрел. никак, без ручной обработки